# Cannot find module 'nodemailer'

Tags: javascript, node.js, zapier

I'm using the Zapier Code application, I need to send an email receiving trello parameters, I'm using a javascript encoding along with node.js, but when I try to find the `nodemailer` module I always get the error that it can not be found.

The error always points to this line of code:

```js
var nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');
```

Comment: Did you try something like [this](https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/131)? If you need more control on the data, you can put some Javascript in between.

Answer (score 20):

It sounds like you have not installed [nodemailer from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer). Navigate to your project folder through a command line terminal and install nodemailer with the below command. If you have a **package.json** file (and you probably should), you can use the `--save` flag to record the version you install with your app.

```
npm install nodemailer --save
```

Note that nodemailer requires Node.js version 6+ to work correctly. Check your Node.js version with `node --version` on Windows or OSX and `nodejs --version` on linux.

Since you're asking this question, you will probably benefit from reading about npm here: https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

Your **package.json** file should have the following dependency. You may have to adjust version number to match Zapier requirements.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemailer": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Upon browsing the Zapier website, it looks like they offer tech support even for free customers. You may consider contacting them directly if this does not resolve your issue.

Comment: Hello friend thank you very much for your attention

I am using the Zapier Code application and in the documentation it informs that it supports Node 4.3.2, do you think I can accomplish my action with these features?

Comment: Are you able to determine the version of Nodemailer that you are using? Is there a record of the version anywhere in your application? I know the Nodemailer website says Nodemailer version 4+ requires Node.js version 6+ https://nodemailer.com/about/

Comment: I can tell the version of node.js that is supported through the application documentation that is available at this link:

https://zapier.com/help/code/

(By searching for "node" on the page, the first result already shows the version).

Does this help in any way?

Comment: Everywhere I look in the Nodemailer documentation says Node.js 6+ is wanted for version 3 and up. Version 2 of nodemailer is no longer supported. You could try setting the package.json dependency to version 2 and see if you have any success.

Comment: You are helping me after 3 hours of searching. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First ensure you call `npm install nodemailer --save` at project root.

Then replace

`Var nodemailer = require ('nodemailer');`

with

`var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');`

Answer (score 1):

You can't import `npm` modules in "Zaps": [Requiring or Using External Libraries](http://zapier.com/help/code/#requiring-or-using-external-libraries)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
npm install nodemailer
```

And your `var nodemailer = require ('nodemailer')` will work.

---

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemailer

Comment: `yarn add nodemailer`. Also you forgot 'er' at the end of `nodemail`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my friend.

I've added this line of code, but now the Zapier Code application tells me: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have a dependency in package.json inside functions**
[image: Make sure you have a dependency in package.json inside functions]